# c shell script doesn't recognize remote server

Tags: unix

On AIX I have a scrip, which ssh to remote server

```
 #!/bin/sh     

 Usage () {     
    echo "Usage: $0 <config_file>"     
 echo "Example:   ./transfer_dmz_startD.sh /export/data/mbsesb/config/transfer_dmz.cfg"     
    exit     
 }          

if [ $# -lt 1 ]    
then    
    usage    
fi    

config_file=${1}    
NAME=`basename $0 .sh`    
LOG=${NAME}.log    
Today=`date '+%Y%m%d'`    
TARFILE=${NAME}.${Today}    
ZIPFILE=${TARFILE}.gz    
DMZ_USER=aaa    
DMZ_HOST=bbbb
TIMESTAMP=`date +%H:%M:%S`    

LOCL_WORKING_DIR=`grep "^local" $config_file | cut -d'=' -f2`    
LOGDIR=`grep "^log" $config_file | cut -d'=' -f2`    
DESTSERVNAME=`grep "^destserver" $config_file | cut -d'=' -f2`    
DAILY_DEST_DIR=`grep "^daily" $config_file | cut -d'=' -f2`    
WEEKLY_DEST_DIR=`grep "^weekly" $config_file | cut -d'=' -f2`    
MONTH_DEST_DIR=`grep "^monthly" $config_file | cut -d'=' -f2`    
LOCLSERVNAME=`grep "^loclserver" $config_file | cut -d'=' -f2`    
LOCL_FILES_DIR=`grep "^mbsesb" $config_file | cut -d'=' -f2`    
LOGF=${LOGDIR}.${LOG}    

mkdir -p ${LOCL_FILES_DIR}/cool_${Today}    

if [ $? != 0 ]    
then    
    echo "Cannot create ${LOCL_FILES_DIR}/cool_${Today}" >>$LOGF   
    echo "Check each directory permission and rerun the program">>$LOGF    
    echo "$NAME terminated abnormaly">>$LOGF    
     mailx -r user@example.com -s "!!!Please read  a $LOGF and make     appropriate action"    
    exit 1    
fi    



ssh ${DMZ_USER}@{$DMZ_HOST}    

if [ $? != 0 ]    
then    
    echo "Cannot connect to $DMZ_USER server, please check connection and re-run the script again">>$LOGF    
    echo "$NAME terminated abnormaly">>$LOGF    
     echo "$NAME.sh cannot connect to ${DMZ_USER}@{$DMZ_HOST}" | mailx  -r user2@example.com -s "!!!Please read  a $LOGF and make appropriate action"    
    exit 1    
fi    

datetime=`date +%p`    

if [ ${datetime} -eq "AM" ]    
than    
    ext=Daily    
else    
    ext=EOD    
fi    
cd  $DAILY_DEST_DIR    

tar -cvf $TARFILE.$ext.tar *$Today*.*    

if [ $? != 0 ]    
then    
    echo "$NAME.sh cannot create tar file on $DMZ_USER server" >>$LOGF    
    echo "email is sending to developer" >>$LOGF    
     mailx -r user@example.com -s "!!!Cannot tar the files on     hbrgmfidmzb1. Please check the files on daily directory"    
fi    

gzip  $TARFILE.$ext.tar    

if [ $? != 0 ]    
then
    echo "$NAME.sh cannot create zip file"    
    echo "email is sending to developer"    
     mailx -r user@example.com -s "!!!Cannot tar the files on hbrgmfidmzb1. Please check the files on daily directory"    
fi
```

After this command the error says:

ssh: Could not resolve hostname {Apsswd}: Hostname and service name not provided or found
The flags you gave make no sense since you're not sending mail.
SSH_KEY are set up, I can connect to that server manually, but script is not working.
Any advice?

Comment: As far as I remember official location of `ssh` command should be in `/usr/bin/ssh` on AIX systems

Comment: Are you new to shell scripting and AIX systems in general?  Are you expecting the lines AFTER the **ssh** to be executed in the remote server?  In the other [question](http://superuser.com/questions/1175990/when-i-run-ssh-dumpremoteserver-get-unexpected-result), you mention **scp**, so what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect invocation of `ssh` command. Correct one is

```
ssh user@host
```

Check `man ssh` manual.

P.S. `ssh` doesn't allow to pass password as a parameter. You need to use either some ssh-agent that asking once for your password that you need manually enter and after that it will supply password to `ssh` automatically or you can use another 3rd party helper such  `sshpass -p 'Password' ssh user@host` (Not sure if it exist on AIX)

Another way to get rid of password is to use public key authentication, this way you providing private key (that was created without password) to `ssh` as

```
ssh -i /path/to/private/key user@host
```

In `csh` variables should be assigned as

```
set HOST = "RealRemoteHostName"
set USER = "SomeUser"
```

then use it in your script as

```
ssh $USER@$HOST
```

P.S.

It turns out after question was updated that it isn't a C Shell (`csh`) but `/bin/sh` and problem seats there

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53158/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-c-shell-script-doesnt-recognize-remote-server).

Comment: At the moment I found something like this: ssh -t $USER@$REMOTE 'ls -l; ps -ef' is working good, but the program exit. I need this program to work further on local machine, check the status and start new script. When I understand, how to do it, I will update this post

Comment: when we make ssh to remote server, we have to do all commands in one line: ssh -t $USER@$REMOTE 'cd /peth/to/dir; tar -cvf tarfile.tar; gzip tarfile.tar'. All we do in quote and separate by semicolon, except last statement

Comment: If you calling `ssh` this way then it supposed to work like that. When you calling `ssh  $USER@$REMOTE` it will login and stay as long until you manually exit, but if you giving remote command inline to `ssh`, then it supposed to do: 1)Login,2)Execute remotely commands you supplied in command line, 3) exit and return to caller exit error of last executed program